# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. ? How solve it?

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a messaging room application that create a discussion chat foreach room between users signed in with same room ,
i m facing this error :

**Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

i used 3 functions :

- getChatMessages() : to get all chat messages from firestore for users
  with same room
- getCurrentRoom():to get the room of the connected user
- getUsers(): return all users with same room

---

chat.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Timestamp } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/timestamp';
import { switchMap,map, timestamp, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { query, orderBy, limit, where } from "firebase/firestore";  
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

 
export interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  displayName:string;
  username?:string;
  room?:string
}
 
export interface Message {
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
  id: string;
  from: string;
  msg: string;
  fromName: string;
  myMsg: boolean;
}
 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {
  currentUser: User ;
  currentRoom:string="";
  updatedRoom:string="";
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.currentUser=user;
      console.log("current email"+this.currentUser.email);
           
  });
}
  async signup({ username,email, password,room }): Promise<any> {
     
    const credential = await this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email,
      password
    );
 
    const uid = credential.user.uid;
 
    return this.afs.doc(
      `users/${uid}`
    ).set({
      uid,
      email: credential.user.email,
      username:username,
      room:room,
    })
  }
 
  signIn({ email, password }) {
    return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }
 
  signOut(): Promise<void> {
    return this.afAuth.signOut();
  }

  addChatMessage(msg) {
    return this.afs.collection('messages').add({
      createdAt:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),//firebase.default.firestore.Timestamp,
      msg: msg,
      from: this.currentUser.uid
    });
  }
   
   

   async getChatMessages() {
    let users = [];
    return   (await this.getUsers()).pipe(
      switchMap(res => {
        users = res;
        console.log("resssssss"+res);
        return this.afs.collection('messages', ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt','asc')).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }) as Observable<Message[]>;
      }),

      map(messages => {
        console.log("messages"+messages);
        // Get the real name for each user
        for (let m of messages) {    
          m.fromName = this.getUserForMsg(m.from, users);
          m.myMsg = this.currentUser.uid === m.from;
        }      
        return messages
      })       
    )
  }
   
 


  public async getCurrentRoom() {
    await this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where("email", "==", this.currentUser.email)).get().toPromise()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
              this.currentRoom=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data())).room;
              console.log("current room" + this.currentRoom);
            });
        });
}
   
public async getUsers() {
  console.log("this room" + this.currentRoom);
  return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where("room", "==", this.currentRoom)).valueChanges({
      idField: 'uid'
  }) as Observable < User[] > ;
}

  private getUserForMsg(msgFromId, users: User[]): string { 
    for (let usr of users) {
      if (usr.uid == msgFromId) {
        return usr.username ?? 'undefind';
      }
    }
    return 'Deleted';
  }


}
```

---

my chat.page.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ChatService } from '../chat.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { finalize, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
export interface FILE {
  name: string;
  filepath: string;
  size: number;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.page.scss'],
})


export class ChatPage implements OnInit {
  ngFireUploadTask: AngularFireUploadTask;

  progressNum: Observable<number>;

  progressSnapshot: Observable<any>;

  fileUploadedPath: Observable<string>;
  room:any;
  files: Observable<FILE[]>;
ImgtoSend:any;
  FileName: string;
  FileSize: number;

  isImgUploading: boolean;
  isImgUploaded: boolean;

  private ngFirestoreCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<FILE>;


  @ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;
 
  messages:any=[];
  newMsg = '';
 
  constructor(private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
    private angularFireStorage: AngularFireStorage,private chatService: ChatService, private router: Router) { 
      this.isImgUploading = false;
      this.isImgUploaded = false;
      
      this.ngFirestoreCollection = angularFirestore.collection<FILE>('filesCollection');
      this.files = this.ngFirestoreCollection.valueChanges();

    }
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.messages= this.chatService.getChatMessages();
  }
    
  sendMessage() {
    this.chatService.addChatMessage(this.newMsg).then(() => {
      this.newMsg = '';
      this.content.scrollToBottom();
    });
  }
 
  signOut() {
    this.chatService.signOut().then(() => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', { replaceUrl: true });
    });
  }








  fileUpload(event: FileList) {
      
    const file = event.item(0)

    if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') { 
      console.log('File type is not supported!')
      return;
    }

    this.isImgUploading = true;
    this.isImgUploaded = false;

    this.FileName = file.name;

    const fileStoragePath = `filesStorage/${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`;
    console.log("filestoragepath"+fileStoragePath);
    const imageRef = this.angularFireStorage.ref(fileStoragePath);
    console.log("image ref"+imageRef);
         
    this.ngFireUploadTask = this.angularFireStorage.upload(fileStoragePath, file);
    this.ImgtoSend=this.FileName;
    console.log("image to Send"+this.ImgtoSend);
    this.progressNum = this.ngFireUploadTask.percentageChanges();
    this.progressSnapshot = this.ngFireUploadTask.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      
      finalize(() => {
        this.fileUploadedPath = imageRef.getDownloadURL();
        console.log("uploaded path"+this.fileUploadedPath);

        this.fileUploadedPath.subscribe(resp=>{
          this.fileStorage({
            name: file.name,
            filepath: resp,
            size: this.FileSize
          });
          this.isImgUploading = false;
          this.isImgUploaded = true;
        },error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
      }),
      tap(snap => {
          this.FileSize = snap.totalBytes;
      })
    )
}


fileStorage(image: FILE) {
    const ImgId = this.angularFirestore.createId();
    
    this.ngFirestoreCollection.doc(ImgId).set(image).then(data => {
      console.log("data"+data);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}  

 
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to eleminate all the code that is not relevant to the question to help people help you.

Second, the issue is simple:

What the compiler is telling you here is, Hey Mohammed Amir, `*ngFor=""` is used to loop through an `Array of objects` while you are passing to it an `object literal`.

Check the value of the property you bind to `*ngFor="let msg of [YourAssumedArrayFromEndpointResponse]"` in your template you will find that `YourAssumedArrayFromEndpointResponse` is not an `array`. That's why the compiler is complaining